# Codeigniter 1.7: Why do I get this error: Fatal error in /..: Cannot redeclare class Error in error.php on line 6

Tags: codeigniter

I have installed grocery_crud into my existing CI v1.7 app, files/pages connects to db and loads fine, however when I click on the **edit** button, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Error in /home/wallace/public_html/wallacep/controllers/wallace/error.php on line 6
```

I then noticed that the url of the edit button is: 
`http://dev1.wallacep.stag/index.php/main/edit/2` it is retaining the index.php.  Now this is a legacy CodeIgniter app, so I can't mess around with the .htaccess file.  The config.php file has a base reference similar to this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://' . trim($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '/') . '/';
```

and the index file section still points to this:
**`$config['index_page'] = "index.php";`**

I adjusted this line, changing it to:**`$config['index_page'] = "";`**

but I still get this: **`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Error in /home/wallace/public_html/wallacep/controllers/wallace/error.php on line 6`**

Also, since this is a legacy application, I am concerned what issues in other places in the site the removal of the index.php has caused that I am not aware of yet.

I went to the error.php page mentioned and all it has is this:

class Error extends Base_Error
{

}

Can anyone point me in the right direction for fixing this issue within grocery_crud?

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a class in scope called Error, You can not have 2 class names called the same thing

You will need to rename the old or the new class to continue

Edit:

to help find it

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass('Error');
echo $reflector->getFileName();
echo $reflector->getStartLine();
```

That should give you the file and the line

Comment: This is just odd.  I did not add an error.php class/page, was already in code and grocery_crud does not have an Error page/class within it.  But I did change the class name to Error1 and that error is no longer appearing, so you are correct.  I need to figure out what grocery_crud is doing to cause this.  Thank you.